# Unable to locate package with apt-get remove

Tags: apt, uninstall, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to remove pip (because I have pip3). I did `sudo apt-get remove --purge pip`, and get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pip
```

But `which pip` gives

```
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

I can confirm that pip doesn't work, because `pip --version` gives

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

How to I clean up my system?

FYI I'm using [Ubuntu on Windows (WSL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about). I really hope this isn't the problem, because everything else seems to be working fine.

Comment: There is no package named pip. Probably you have `python-pip` package. (though WSL may be different..?

Comment: @doug I also tried `sudo apt-get remove python-pip`, doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `apt list | grep pip` to find the package name?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have `pip3`, you need to uninstall `python3-pip`.